# JAXB unmarshall Mixed Content

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm trying to parse existing XML files for a java application and some of the elements have mixed content occasionally as demonstrated below:

XML_STRING

```xml
<root>
  <name>Michael</name>
  <question>Text here</question>
</root>
```

XML_STRING_2

```xml
<root>
  <name>Michael</name>
  <question>Text here<measure>More Text</measure></question>
</root>
```

I Made the below classes to unmarshall this data.

Root Class

```java
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root implements Serializable
{
    private String name;
    private Question question;
}
```

Question Class

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Question implements Serializable
{
    @XmlValue
    private String questionText;
    private String measure;
}
```

I can't seem to get both the `Text Here` and `More Text` to be stored inside the `Question` class.

```java
JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class)
  .createUnmarshaller()
  .unmarshal(new ByteArrayInputStream(XML_STRING_2.getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

I'm printing the result of the above code snippet (with Lombok's `@ToString()` annotation added to `Root` and `Question`) for both `XML_STRING` and `XML_STRING_2`.

**XML_STRING**: `Root(name=Michael, question=Question(questionText=Text here, measure=null))`
**XML_STRING_2**:`Root(name=Michael, question=Question(questionText=, measure=null))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get something I could work with by using `@XmlMixed` along with `@XmlElementRefs` inside `Question` and creating a `Measure` class.

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Question implements Serializable
{
    @XmlMixed
    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(name = "measure", type=Measure.class)
    })
    private List<?> content;
}
```

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="measure") // If this is removed I get the error: "Invalid @XmlElementRef : Type `Measure` or any of its subclasses are not known to this context."
public class Measure
{
    @XmlValue
    private String value;
}
```

I'm now getting the below output, which i can use via instanceof checking the items inside `content`

```
Root(name=Michael, question=Question(content=[Text here]))
Root(name=Michael, question=Question(content=[Text here, Measure(value=More Text)]))
```

The Root file remained unchanged.